# How to determine the DC power rating of a switch marked with AC rating

Tags: switches

Could you help me?

I want to use a switch to flip a power supply between two different circuits. The power supply is 220 V DC at 15 mA. I realise this is a high DC voltage compared to a very small current.

The 3PDT switch I've found in my box of stuff can do 250 V AC at 3 A but I can't work out what it's DC rating is. I'm guessing a switch can work with a much higher AC voltage than DC but I just can't seem to work out what switch rating will work for me to switch me 220 VDC @ 15 mA.

Could you guys help me?

Thanks.

Comment: DC ratings of switches are often a factor of  5 or 10 times less than AC since DC arcing is much more damaging than AC, so that 230VAC switch is not what you want.  Either see if you can find one rated for the voltage you need, or see if you can rethink your circuit to avoid a mechanical switch at high voltage.

Comment: Ah ok thank you for that. As I suspect finding a 220v DC switch will be hard to find for a small circuit, is there anything else that I could do? I basically have a power supply with two different audio circuits. I will only use one circuit at a time so wanted to use one power supply and simply switch between each circuit. The power supply is rated as 220VDC at 15ma and each circuit needs exactly that power. If I connected the one supply to each circuit simulataneously, eg parallel I suspect the combined amount of current draw would be more than the power supply could handle

Comment: Any reason the power supply has to be live while you switch loads?  Could rig up a cover or panel around a low voltage switch that cuts the AC power to the circuit when you lift it.  That way you only switch when the power is off.  Probably safer for your equipment as well.

Comment: Thanks I'm sorry I dont quite understand how you mean. Could you explain to me again? I'm sorry I'm still learning about electronics

Comment: The DC voltage rating on switches also assume max current. If a switch can insulate AC voltage for a moment, it can do the same forever at the same voltage DC. The issue is arcing, but at only 15ma, you don't really need to worry about that at all for your application. In short: the switch should work fine; at worst, it will wear out slightly sooner than expected.

Comment: It depends if the load is inductive. There's little possibility that the load is a huge coil if it draws only 15mA, but it's better to ask.

Comment: Ah ok dandavis thank you. Bobflux, what do you mean by "if its inductive"? Thank you

Comment: an inductive load would be a magnetic coil like a fan, ballast, transformer, solenoid, etc. A backwards dioxide can help reduce the impact of such "kickback" on the switch, if it's a problem at all, which is doubtful. Remember that if the switch fails, it either won't turn on or won't turn off - not a calamity. At 15ma, you don't need to worry about over heating from a slowly developing high resistance due to incremental damage.

Comment: Ah thats great. Thank you !